# Custom metrics with tf.estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I want tensorflow to calculate the coefficient of determination (R squared) during evaluation of my estimator. I tried to implement it in the following way loosly based on the implementation of the official metrics:

```
def r_squared(labels, predictions, weights=None,
              metrics_collections=None,
              updates_collections=None,
              name=None):

    total_error = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(labels - tf.reduce_mean(labels)))
    unexplained_error = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(labels - predictions))
    r_sq = 1 - tf.div(unexplained_error, total_error)

    # update_rsq_op = ?

    if metrics_collections:
        ops.add_to_collections(metrics_collections, r_sq)

    # if updates_collections:
    #     ops.add_to_collections(updates_collections, update_rsq_op)

    return r_sq #, update_rsq_op
```

Then, I use this function as a metric in the EstimatorSpec:

```
estim_specs = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
    ...
    eval_metric_ops={
        'r_squared': r_squared(labels, predictions),
        ...
    })
```

However, this fails since my implementation of R squared doesn't return an update_op.

```
TypeError: Values of eval_metric_ops must be (metric_value, update_op) tuples, given: Tensor("sub_4:0", dtype=float64) for key: r_squared
```

Now I wonder, what exactly is the update_op supposed to do? Do I actually need to implement an update_op or can I somehow create some kind of dummy update_op? And if it is necessary, how would I implement it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom eval\_metric\_ops in Estimator in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643809/custom-eval-metric-ops-in-estimator-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to figure it out. I can wrap my metric in a mean metric and use its update_op. This seems to work for me.

```
def r_squared(labels, predictions, weights=None,
              metrics_collections=None,
              updates_collections=None,
              name=None):

    total_error = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(labels - tf.reduce_mean(labels)))
    unexplained_error = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(labels - predictions))
    r_sq = 1 - tf.div(unexplained_error, total_error)

    m_r_sq, update_rsq_op = tf.metrics.mean(r_sq)

    if metrics_collections:
        ops.add_to_collections(metrics_collections, m_r_sq)

    if updates_collections:
        ops.add_to_collections(updates_collections, update_rsq_op)

    return m_r_sq, update_rsq_op
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this in tensorflow 2 without using `tf.compat.v1` modules?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would mention that you could just use [`tensorflow_addons.metrics.RQsquare()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/RSquare). Tensorflow Add Ons is [on PyPi here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-addons/) and the documentation is a [part of Tensorflow here](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons). All you have to do is set `y_shape` to the shape of your output, often it is `(1,)` for a single output variable.